# Running JMeter report genaration on Mac

Tags: macos, jmeter

I have a working command using a windows machine like this:

```
jmeter -g /Users/magnus/Desktop/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/report_QA/sfm_qa_Oppdater.csv -o /Users/magnus/Desktop/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/result_QA_oppdate
```

given I am standing in the directory where JMeter is installed.

However if I run the same command on my Mac I get: jmeter not found

How do I run the same command on a mac using "terminal"

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `jmeter` then MacOS is trying to find this binary or script under system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), if it is not there - you will get `not found` error.

So either you need to put "bin" folder of your JMeter installation under your system PATH like:

```
PATH=/Users/magnus/Desktop/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin:$PATH && export PATH
```

then you will be able to run it as `jmeter`

Or change your command to explicitly invoke the [`jmeter.sh` startup script](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4/bin/jmeter.sh)  like:

```
./jmeter -g /Users/magnus/Desktop/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/report_QA/sfm_qa_Oppdater.csv -o /Users/magnus/Desktop/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/result_QA_oppdate
```

this `./` bit is uber important

More information: [How to Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)

And last but not the least, you can install JMeter via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), the formulae will download the latest JMeter version and put it into your PATH

Comment: But I get "permission denied: ./jmeter" running the command "./jmeter -g /Users/magnus/Desktop/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/report_QA/sfm_qa_Oppdater.csv -o /Users/magnus/Desktop/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/result_QA_oppdate". is this due to content allready in the folder or do I need to "run as adminstrator" in some way?

Answer (score 0):

To run the script in non-GUI mode, you have to just add `sh` before the same windows non-GUI command.

Go to your bin directory and run like:

```
sh jmeter -n -t Test.jmx -l Test1.jtl -g test.csv
```